# Disable email updates alert on expired domain

Tags: emails, updating, notifications

As per question, my domain already expired for over months now and im not planning on using it anymore but i keep getting the modules updates email alert coming from the domain.
How can i disable it since i can no longer access the domain to change the setting. I find its kinda weird how the domain still able to send the email.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the FTP folders where you uploaded Drupal just remove the folder where you previously installed Drupal. If you can't access it anymore, there's not much you can do. You can setup a filter in your mailbox though.